# How do I view the entire raw message in alpine?

Tags: alpine-mail

I am fiddling around with S/MIME emails (sent from https://ttpedge.sitenv.org/ttp/#/hisp/smtp).

I want to view the entire email, but when I export the message I get this:

```
From wwerner@transport-testing.nist.gov Wed Apr 16 11:02:03 2014
Date: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 12:02:04 -0400 (EDT)
From: wwerner@transport-testing.nist.gov
To: wwerner@not-a-chance.com
Subject: Direct Validation Request



    [ Part 1, Application/PKCS7-MIME (Name: "smime.p7m") 27 KB. ]
    [ Unable to print this part. ]
```

Instead, I expect to see something more like this:

```
Received: from hit-testing.nist.gov (unknown [])
        by mydomain.com (Postfix) with SMTP id 552EDB606BC
        for <wwerner@direct.mydomain.com>; Wed, 16 Apr 2014 13:54:21 -0500 (CDT)
Subject: Direct Validation Request
Date: Wed, 16 Apr 2014 14:54:23 -0400 (EDT)
From: wwerner@transport-testing.nist.gov
To: wwerner@direct.mydomain.com
Message-ID: <2027534107.69.1397674463912.JavaMail.root@transport-testing.nist.gov>
Subject: Message test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name=smime.p7m; 
        smime-type=enveloped-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
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```

I just tried saving the attachment and apparently it's saving it in a binary format. If I look at this in Gmail's "original" view it shows up b64 encoded (of course this is probably obvious as I'm looking at it in the browser).

Do I have to convert the attachment myself? Or is there a way I can export it b64 encoded.

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you are trying to do. One simple way to do this is just save the message to a different folder, and then that message will basically be that file. Can you say more explicitly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - I just added an example of what I'm looking to see.

Comment: Ok,this is essentially what you get if you do what I suggested above. Though you get an extra "This text is part of the internal format of your mail folder," bit on top. However, I still don't understand why you are trying o do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this, which assumes you save your mail in mbox format, is just save the message to a different folder with no other messages. Then, the file which corresponds to that folder in `~/Mail` will contain essentially that message. It will also contain Pine/Alpines "placeholder" message:

> This text is part of the internal format of your mail folder, and is
>   not a real message.  It is created automatically by the mail system
>   software. If deleted, important folder data will be lost, and it will
>   be re-created with the data reset to initial values.

but that is easy to remove.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you can press "h" and have it switched (forth and back).

This confirms it: http://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/help/faq?faqid=1080#pine

> 1. In Alpine, open the message for viewing.
> 2. Type **h** so as to switch on viewing of full headers.
>
>    **If you only wanted to view the full headers, you need not read further, but if you want to forward a copy of the headers, continue as
>      shown below.**
>
>    ---
> 3. Type **f** to forward the message.
> 4. Pine may ask you if you want to forward the message as an
>      attachment; answer **No** to this.
> 5. Enter the forwarding address and any notes of your own above the
>      forwarded text.
> 6. Enter **CTRL-X** (hold down **CTRL** and type **x**) to send the message.

---

Then you can export the message to a file and read it afterwards:

> **PINE**
>
> When viewing the message in question, use the “E” command to export
>   the message to a text file.   This file will contain the full raw
>   message source, starting with the full headers.

Via: https://luxsci.com/blog/viewing-the-message-source-full-headers-of-an-email.html

---

Example via my Alpine 2.21.  **Usual view**:

```
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 15:28:23 -0000
From: The PocketFMS Foundation <noreply@pocketfms.com>
To: saulius2@ar.fi.lt
Subject: EasyVFR Basic is now available for free in the UK and the Netherlands.

.
 
 
Click here [www.pocketfms.com] to view this e-mail in your web browser.
 
[image-6.jpg] [www.easyvfr.aero]
 
 
[image-15.png]
 
Rotate your device for the best viewing experience!
 
 
 
 
Free version EasyVFR now available
in UK and NL
[...]
```

Display whith **full headers on**:

```
Return-Path: <noreply@pocketfms.com>
X-Original-To: saulius2@ar.fi.lt
Delivered-To: saulius2@ar.fi.lt
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by tvarka.ar.fi.lt (Postfix) with ESMTP id 10DB0C0BC6
    for <saulius2@ar.fi.lt>; Tue, 13 Jun 2017 18:42:27 +0300 (EEST)
Received: from tvarka.ar.fi.lt ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (tvarka.ar.fi.lt [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id drJmckwq9NY3 for <saulius2@ar.fi.lt>;
    Tue, 13 Jun 2017 18:42:25 +0300 (EEST)
Received: from members.pocketfms.com (members.pocketfms.com [93.158.218.198])
    by tvarka.ar.fi.lt (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6A300C0A8A
    for <saulius2@ar.fi.lt>; Tue, 13 Jun 2017 18:42:24 +0300 (EEST)
Received: from MapServer1 ([93.158.218.198]) by members.pocketfms.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Tue, 13 Jun 2017 15:28:23 +0000
Organization: The PocketFMS Foundation
Reply-To: noreply@pocketfms.com
Message-ID: <c95250f8bb17c122099605d600265862@pocketfms.com>
From: "The PocketFMS Foundation" <noreply@pocketfms.com>
To: <saulius2@ar.fi.lt>
Subject: =?windows-1252?Q?EasyVFR_Basic_is_now_available_for_free_in_the_UK_and_the_Netherlands.?=
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 15:28:23 -0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="windows-1252"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 13 Jun 2017 15:28:23.0972 (UTC) FILETIME=[B22D9640:01D2E459]


<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" =
xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" =
xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head><meta =
http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">
[...]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows the message headers, not the full, raw email. I ended out using some Python tools to simply write the message out to a file. I could have also used Python's `mbox` library to extract it from my mailbox but if there's a way to view this within Alpine, I haven't seen it yet :-\

Comment: In my case I am running Alpine 2.21.  If I press "h", I get both full headers and raw email content (often encoded in one way or another).  I updated my answer to visualize this.  And if I export msg while full headers are on, it stays the same as the mbox-file in which it it saved (except for the first line, non-significant).